# Nuxt 3 Tiptap editor custom components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tiptap

i'm currently implementing the Tiptap editor in my Nuxt 3 Project.
(with this Module: https://nuxt.com/modules/tiptap)

And i want to have a functionality to add custom components in the content. Like a Wrapper for specific content or product cards or something. Is this in any way possible? And when yes, how?